# Why air spacing for high power beam splitters?

Tags: optics, optical-materials

Ordinary glass cube beam splitters are constructed with a dielectric or hybrid coating on the hypotenuse of a right angle prism which is then cemented to another right angle  prism.   These fail in high energy applications because the cement absorbs enough energy to cause problems.

For higher power applications, the two prisms are optically contacted so that there is no cement to fail.

I have read that for even higher power applications, the prisms are air spaced.

Are these air spaced prisms constructed by coating one prism, and bringing it close to, but not touching, the second prism?  If so, why do these have a higher damage threshold than optically contacted prisms?   Is the spacing chosen to be large enough to avoid frustrated total internal reflection?

Or, when people refer to air spaced prisms do they mean that the mechanism is frustrated total internal reflection, and there is no coating on either prism?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the geometry you describe brings to mind [the frustration of total-internal-reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection#Frustrated_total_internal_reflection) which may play a role here.

Answer (score 1):

There's a really good answer [in another thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86398/high-power-beam-splitting). Basically its FTIR that's causing the one part of the beam, and evanescent waves that couple to the second prism for the second beam. That way there's no coating to burn off.

The air is not important, just the spacing of the gap, which controls how much of the beam goes where. Vacuum works just as well, but is obviously somewhat more difficult to arrange. I suspect vacuum gapped versions are common in NIF though.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that thread.  What is not clear to me is if the term "air spaced prism" means exactly the same thing as "FTIR prism".

Comment: Hmmm, "air spaced prism" I can't say, but google suggests "air spaced beam splitter" does ultimately devolve to F-TIR, potentially through Glan.

Comment: Argh!  I'm constantly saying "prism" when I mean "beamsplitter".   "Air spaced beam splitter" vs. "FTIR beam splitter".  (I actually typed "prism" just now.)  Sorry.  And I'm definitely talking about glass here.